ansible import_playbook with variable in name
I want to use a variable in the path of the playbook
ansible.builtin.import_playbook: "{{ home_directory_of_user }}/.ansible/.......

I do have:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - "{{ var_file }}"
  tasks:
    - name: var_file
      set_fact:
        ansible_collections_directory: "{{ ansible_collections_directory }}"

- name: Import the k3s playbook with flannel
  ansible.builtin.import_playbook: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['ansible_collections_directory'] }}/techno_tim/k3s_ansible/site.yml"
    vars:
      ansible_collections_directory: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['ansible_collections_directory'] }}"

With this I do get this error:
ERROR! 'hostvars' is undefined.

When I debug the value, I do get the correct path, so it has to be about how to set the variable in the name of the import_playbook
Does anybody know how to use a variable in the playbook name?
Thanks

It looks like you're in the middle of an A/B problem, so I'll give you two answers.
Answer to your question

When I debug the value, I do get the correct path, so it has to be about how to set the variable in the name of the import_playbook

Yes - because when you debug the value it is in the scope of the hosts where you're running the debug task (it always runs on the controller, though, but it doesn't matter here).
import_playbook is not a task thus it's outside the scope of any host - so there is no hostvars.

Does anybody know how to use a variable in the playbook name?

You can use the vars keyword like you already do but you can't assign any value from hostvars to it:
# playbook.yaml
---
- name: Import a playbook with a variable in name
  ansible.builtin.import_playbook: "{{ playbook_to_import }}"
  vars:
    playbook_to_import: playbook-to-import.yml

You can override that value with --extra-vars according to the rules of precedence:
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --extra-vars playbook_to_import=another-playbook-to-import.yml

Answer to the real question - how to use playbooks from collections
Your code incidcates that you're trying to use a playbook from techno-tim/k3s-ansible, so some other rules apply. As usual, this is described in Ansible documentation - Using a playbook from a collection:
- name: Import a playbook
  ansible.builtin.import_playbook: my_namespace.my_collection.playbookX

Of course, the collection has to be properly installed with ansible-galaxy.
So in your case, just set the right collection name and don't play with any variables:
- name: Import the k3s playbook with flannel
  ansible.builtin.import_playbook: techno_tim.k3s_ansible.site


Thanks, but I am looking for something else and of today, I got it working.

This is working, values do come from the vars_files:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    destination_group_vars_all_directory: "{{ ansible_playbooks_directory }}/group_vars"
    install_k3s: "{{ install_k3s }}"
  vars_files:
    - "{{ var_file }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Save the variables for the k3s playbook
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        k3s_version: "{{ k3s_version }}"
        k3s_token: "{{ k3s_token }}"
        k3s_cni: "{{ k3s_cni }}"
        apiserver_endpoint: "{{ k8s_loadbalancer_api_ip }}"
        k3s_master_taint: "{{ k8s_taint_masters }}"
        kube_vip_lb_ip_range: "{{ k8s_loadbalancer_ip_range }}"
        k8s_interface: "{{ k8s_interface }}"
        ansible_collections_directory: "{{ ansible_collections_directory }}"
        install_k3s: "{{ install_k3s }}"

- name: Import the k3s playbook with flannel
  ansible.builtin.import_playbook: site.yml
  vars:
    k3s_version: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['k3s_version'] }}"
    k3s_token: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['k3s_token'] }}"
    apiserver_endpoint: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['apiserver_endpoint'] }}"
    k3s_master_taint: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['k3s_master_taint'] }}"
    kube_vip_lb_ip_range: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['kube_vip_lb_ip_range'] }}"
    k3s_cni: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['k3s_cni'] }}"
    install_k3s: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['install_k3s'] }}"
    flannel_iface: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['k8s_interface'] }}"

